# Check if a point is near a rectangle border

Tags: android

I have 4 points making a rectangle. I would like to know if another point in the view is near the border of that rectangle. It is not if the point is IN the rectangle or OUTSIDE of the rectangle. The idea is to know if the point is near (for example 25 pixels) from the rectangle.

What I am making is a rectangle to let the user re-size a view. If the user clicks outside of the rectangle then the changes are saved. All this is easy, but I also want to save changes when the user clicks inside the rectangle.

[image]

In this example I would like to detect if the user touches in the gray or pink area, and not in the black area (where probably is touching on the blue dots or around them)

Comment: Knock up the bigger (black)rectangle, it's near if it's inside that one but outside of the mauve one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code to solve the problem:

```
float distance = 25.0f;    // constant distance
if ( ( point.x < rect.left && point.x > rect.left - distance ) ||
     ( point.x > rect.right && point.x < rect.right + distance ) ||
     ( point.y < rect.bottom && point.y > rect.bottom - distance ) ||
     ( point.y > rect.top && point.y < rect.top + distance ) )  {
    // point is in black area
}
else  {
    // point is in pink/grey area
}
```

Just define **distance** to be the size around the rectangle to exclude, and make sure that both the point and rectangle coordinates are in the same coordinate system.